# Retain veelo chapter number box when changing margin size

Tags: memoir

I am using the `veelo` chapter style of `memoir` with these settings:

```
\chapterstyle{veelo}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\pagestyle{companion}
\nouppercaseheads

\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\flushright}

% Fit to the paper size requested
\setstocksize{23cm}{16cm}
\settrimmedsize{23cm}{16cm}{*}
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}
\settypeblocksize{18cm}{12cm}{*}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{*}{*}{*}

\setheadfoot{30pt}{30pt}
\setheaderspaces{1cm}{*}{*}
\headsep = 25pt
\checkandfixthelayout

% header
\makerunningwidth{companion}{12cm}
\makeheadposition{companion}{center}{center}{center}{center}
\makeheadrule{companion}{12cm}{0.2pt}
```

It is all working fine producing this:

[image]

But I now I need to reduce the margins of the page by changing `\settypeblocksize{18cm}{12cm}{*}` to `\settypeblocksize{18cm}{11cm}{*}` but when I do that, the box next to the chapter number disappears resulting in:

[image]

Comment: I made the code you posted into an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) trying to fill in all that you missed. When I processed it I got an error message about `\resize` box being undefined. Please provode a an MWE showing what you have done.

Comment: @PeterWilson Thank you Peter. I am using RMarkdown in Rstudio so the options are not contained in a single file. What is an MWE? I can google around and try to get it to work autonomously.

EDIT: oh I get it, minimal working example 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I revised my initial MWE by including the `graphicx` package which is needed if the `veelo` chapterstyle is used.

It seemed to me that you had got mixed up your description of the problem. A typeblock size of 18 by 12 cm has smaller side margins than an 18 by 11 cm typeblock. The narrower the margin the less room there is for the black box. The follwing gives you some options for setting the width of the typeblock, and hence the margins.

```
% veeloprob.tex  SE 596511

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\twlen} \setlength{\twlen}{11cm}
%\setlength{\twlen}{12cm}
%\setlength{\twlen}{10cm}
\setlength{\twlen}{11.5cm}

% Fit to the paper size requested
\setstocksize{23cm}{16cm}
\settrimmedsize{23cm}{16cm}{*}
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}
%\settypeblocksize{18cm}{12cm}{*}
%\settypeblocksize{18cm}{11cm}{*}
\settypeblocksize{18cm}{\twlen}{*}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{*}{*}{*}

\setheadfoot{30pt}{30pt}
\setheaderspaces{1cm}{*}{*}
\headsep = 25pt
\checkandfixthelayout

\chapterstyle{veelo}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\pagestyle{companion}
\nouppercaseheads

\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\flushright}


% header
\makerunningwidth{companion}{\twlen}%{12cm}
\makeheadposition{companion}{center}{center}{center}{center}
\makeheadrule{companion}{\twlen}{0.2pt}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{First chapter}

The \verb!\midchapskip! is \the\midchapskip

Some text.

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

Note: It is better to set the document layout parameters before calling on anything that depends on those and also the textwidth value should be used in the header settings, both of which I have done above.

It is up to you to decide on the optimum relationship between the `veelo` style and the textwidth/margins. Currently the spine and fore-edge margins are equal, which is not the usual case for two-sided printing. Specifying a smaller spine margin and bigger fore-margin (typically the fore-margin is twice the spine margin) would give more space for the black box.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used a different approach so here it is in case someone is interested:

```
\newlength{\numberheight}
\setlength{\numberheight}{\beforechapskip}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
  \enspace\resizebox{!}{\numberheight}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}%
  \rlap{\hspace{1cm}\rule{\midchapskip}{\beforechapskip}}%
}
```